# Multilingual site same domain homepage issue

Tags: magento2, multi-language

We are having a small issue on our multilingual website, https://www.derrampenshop.de
When we are on the "German " store view the homepage works perfectly but if we select the "English" store view it directs me to a product and even if I disable this product it will send us to a 404 no-route page.

I am new to this, so anyone can advise how can we sort this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: hi Everyone, the product displayed was a self created product with "no" URL set that why it was distrubing our home page. If you took time to check many thanks :)

Comment: I can see the English page without any 404 and german page fine too. Can you clear your cache and try once?

Comment: Hi Rahul, I have sorted that , is all good now but thanks for checking.